# How to find source of unusual icons in OSX El Capitan script menus?

Tags: android, macos, icons

How can I find the source of the unusual icons in the script menus of OSX El Capitan 10.11.1 (and also in Public Beta 10.11.2)? See [this screenshot](http://skyprod.net/~mcook/images/Screen_Shot_2015-11-01_at_16.27.47.png) and [this clip](http://skyprod.net/~mcook/images/Screenshot_new_Icon_clipped.png). These seem to come from my Android phone but I cannot see where.

I have removed all the /opt* and /usr/local/* references that were specified in my PATH in ~/.profile. I have also removed the .android folder from my home directory as and the Android apps from my /Applications folder, but nothing seems to help despite rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by uninstalling the USB driver for my Android phone (Motorola E 2nd Gen LTE).

The Uninstaller was "/Library/Application Support/Motorola Mobility/Uninstall Motorola Device Manager".